# Creating commits with Gitlab API and CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to use the [Gitlab api to create a commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions) to create several commits on a single branch, but I'm worried that Gitlab's CI will activate for each commit.

Will creating a commit using the repository/commits api trigger CI? If not, is there a way to manually trigger CI when I'm done? If it will, is there a way to supress it, like `git push -o ci.skip` ([see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skipping-jobs))

Answer (score 0):

A commit created by an API call is treated as a regular git commit. This means it will trigger your CI if it matches the conditions of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
If you want to skip the CI add `[skip ci]` to your commit message.